# Docusign Error: "EDITOR_MUST_HAVE_ACCOUNT" when adding editor recipient to an envelope (Dev Sandbox)

Tags: docusignapi

I'm testing the Docusing API using the Dev Sandbox and I get the following error when I try to create an envelope with an embedded editor:

```
{
    "errorCode": "EDITOR_MUST_HAVE_ACCOUNT",
    "message": "The recipient Editor must be an existing DocuSign account  member."
}
```

I'm defining the email, name, clientUserId and recipientId parameters using my Sandbox account data, which works properly if I add and agent recipient instead of an editor one.

I guess it might be a limitation of the Sandbox account, but can't find any information about it.

Update: if I add the editor recipient without specifying a clientUserId, the envelope is created correctly, so the problem may be related to that. I've already checked that the SignerMustHaveAccount and SignerMustLoginToSign options are false.

P.S. We are trying to integrate the Docusing API in our system: we want to let our clients use the embedded sender feature, but we don't want them to be able to see the envelopes of other customers when they get logged in. We can't create one account per customer either, so I thought we could achieve our goal by having one user to create the envelopes (through API calls in our code) and another user to edit them as an editor recipient using the embedded feature. Am I right?

Comment: Hmm that's weird, normally I'd say the error message is quite clear in that it wants the recipient you are setting as an `Editor` to have their own DocuSign account, however if you're saying it works when you do not set the `clientUserId` property on the recipient then I'm not sure what's going on.  It's possible there's a bug or something else going on, do you have a DocuSign Account Manager?

Comment: Not yet @Ergin, at this moment we're just using a dev account and the demo API, that's why I first thought it could be a limitation. But after checking that it works without the `clientUserId`, either I'm doing something wrong (probably) or like you say there's a bug somewhere. Anyway, using an editor recipient doesn't comply with our security requirements either, so we opted for the anchor tags when creating envelops and it's going well so far. I'm still curious about the error though, if I got time I'll keep investigating and post any update. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hi, why can't you create an account per customer? If the customers have accounts then they can also see the status of their envelopes. If there is a business issue that you only want the customers to be able to send out envelopes via your integration, there are ways to set up the account to enforce that. Also, you can get set up to enable programmatic creation of your customer's accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @LarryK, the problem is not so much that we can't but that we don't want to face the complication of having one account per customer, specially when we can avoid it. Creating the envelopes using anchoring tabs is simpler and let us build the new functionalities we want to offer to our customers, so for now we'll stick with it.